# Custom space in regression output table (i do not want to use default \\)

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to present results of a regression and I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[article]{abntex2}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage{lmodern}            
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{nomencl}            
\usepackage{color}              
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{setspace}           
\usepackage[hang, bottom]{footmisc}     
\usepackage{caption}            
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
            \centering 
              \caption{title} 
              \label{}

            \smallskip
            \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{d{5}} @{}} 
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Dependent variable} \\ 
            \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$depvar$} \\[1ex] 
            & \mc{all obs} & \mc{excl.\ outliers}\\ 
            \midrule
             $x1$ & -1.347^{***} & -1.367^{***} \\ 
              & (0.467) & (0.468) \\ [1ex]
             $x2$ & -0.344^{**} & -0.333^{*} \\ 
              & (0.169) & (0.174) \\ [1ex]
             $x3$ & 3.769^{**} & 3.659^{**} \\ 
              & (1.755) & (1.755) \\ [1ex]
             $Constant$ & -32.650^{***} & -32.697^{***} \\ 
              & (1.790) & (1.793) \\ [1ex]
            \midrule
            Observations & 5,562 & 5,557 \\
            Log Likelihood & -1,324.764 & -1,321.730 \\
            Akaike Inf. Crit. & 2,671.528 & 2,665.459 \\
            \addlinespace
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize Note: $^{*}\, p<0.1$; $^{**}\, p<0.05$; $^{***}\, p<0.01$}


        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Between the lines of each covariate I have this `& & \\` as a default space. I want to customize the size of that space. How can I do that?

(PS: I do not want to use `\arraystretch` because its not about the spaces between lines, but only between variables.)

Comment: You can `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<value>}` inside the `table` environment and this setting will disappear with `\end{table}`.

Comment: What's the reason for writing `$-$1.347$^{***}$` instead of `$-1.347^{***}$`, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would focus mainly on decluttering the appearance of the table -- why the unnecessary switches to italics? are you a fan of "ransom note" aesthetics?! -- and on aligning the numbers in columns 2 and 3 on their decimal markers. I would also employ the `booktabs` package for its well-spaced horizontal lines (`\toprule`, `\cmidrule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`) rather than the basic `\hline` and `\cline` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, and \cmidrule macros
\usepackage{dcolumn} % alignment of numbers on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering 
  \caption{Regression results} 
  \label{} 

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{d{3.5}} @{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Dependent variable} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-3} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{depvar} \\[1ex] 
& \mc{all obs} & \mc{excl.\ outliers}\\ 
\midrule
 $x_1$ & -1.347^{***} & -1.367^{***} \\ 
  & (0.467) & (0.468) \\[1ex]
 $x_2$ & -0.344^{**} & -0.333^{*} \\ 
  & (0.169) & (0.174) \\[1ex]
 $x_{3t}$ & -32.650^{***} & -32.697^{***} \\ 
  & (1.790) & (1.793) \\  
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize Note: $^{*}\, p<0.1$; $^{**}\, p<0.05$; $^{***}\, p<0.01$}
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to deal with the OP's updated example code: The main change you need to make to get rid of the overfull-box complaints is to change the definitions of columns 2 and 3 from `d{5}` to `d{5.6}` -- you weren't allowing any space for the decimal parts of the numbers. Also, do make sure to encase the commas that act as thousands-separators in curly braces; that way, TeX won't treat them as punctuation marks.

For crying out loud, don't write `$depvar$` and `$Constant$`. Instead, do please write `\textit{depvar}` and `\textit{Constant}`. If you don't understand the difference between math mode italics and text italics, please pick up any basic introductory-level treatise on TeX and/or LaTeX and study the basics of the difference between text and math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[article]{abntex2}

\usepackage{cmap}      
\usepackage{lmodern}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{nomencl}   
\usepackage{color}     
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{setspace}           
\usepackage[hang, bottom]{footmisc}     
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}   
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering 
\caption{title} 
\label{}

   \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{d{5.6}} @{}} 
   \toprule
   & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Dependent variable:} \\ 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textit{depvar}} \\
   \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
   & \mc{all obs} & \mc{excl.\ outliers}\\ 
   \midrule
    $x_1$ & -1.347^{***} & -1.367^{***} \\ 
    & (0.467) & (0.468) \\ [1ex]
    $x_2$ & -0.344^{**} & -0.333^{*} \\ 
    & (0.169) & (0.174) \\ [1ex]
    $x_3$ & 3.769^{**} & 3.659^{**} \\ 
    & (1.755) & (1.755) \\ [1ex]
    \textit{Constant} & -32.650^{***} & -32.697^{***} \\ 
    & (1.790) & (1.793) \\ %[1ex]
   \midrule
   Observations & 5{,}562 & 5{,}557 \\
   Log Likelihood & -1{,}324.764 & -1{,}321.730 \\
   AIC & 2{,}671.528 & 2{,}665.459 \\
   \bottomrule
   \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize %
     Note: $^{*}\, p<0.1$; $^{**}\, p<0.05$; $^{***}\, p<0.01$}


    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @Mico, thanks for you answer.
I used the default code of the stargazer R package.
I have two questions:
1) even though my table is looking far better now, I have the following attention message: "overfull \hbox (.... too wide) detected at line ...". What settings should I adjust to avoid that?
2) If I want to put the number of observations in the end I will have a number with a thousand separator and not a decimal one, so it will not be aligned. How can I fix that?
Thank you!
Wagner

Comment: @WagnerOliveira - It's really difficult to answer your questions without having a compilable example to work with. Pleaes either edit your exisint posting or create a new query, with code that generates all the issues you need to fix. Thanks.

Comment: Roger, @Mico. Just updated the code in the question above. Thanks!

Comment: @WagnerOliveira - I'm afraid your updated code is not compilable. Do please state which document class you employ, how wide the text block is, and which packages you load. Thanks.

Comment: thats done, @Mico

Comment: thank you for your answer and advice, @Mico, It's working fine now. I'm quite a newbie in TeX yet, so I'm learning quite a lot here in the forums!

Answer (score 3):

I propose this code, which uses  the `\addlinespace` command, from `booktabs`. It adds a default vertical spacing of 0.5em, but this maybe changed using the optional argument of the command, or changing the value of `\defaultaddspace`. In addition, the rules from booktabs have some vertical padding.

In addition, I used the  `S` column type from `siunitx`, to have an alignment of the numeric calues on the decimal dot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, float}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H] \centering
\sisetup{table-format=-1.3,table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-pre=(), table-align-text-pre=false, table-space-text-post= $^{***}$}
  \caption{Result of the regression}
  \label{}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lSS}
\toprule
\midrule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{depvar} \\
& {(all obs)} & {(without outliers)} \\
\midrule]
 x1 & 1.347$ ^{***} $ & -1.367 $^{***}$ \\
  & {(}0.467{)} & {(}0.468{)} \\
\addlinespace
 x2 & -0.344$^{**}$ & -.333$^{*}$ \\
  & {(}0.169{)} &{(}0.174{)} \\
\addlinespace
 x3t & -32.650$^{***}$ & -32.697$^{***}$ \\
  & {(}1.790{)} & {(}1.793{)}\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]